# Regex - search for 2 words in a string

Tags: regex

I have the following lines in a text file (simple example, actual text file I need to work in is 7,000 lines long):

1. The kitchen delivery arrived
2. In the afternoon Dad helped install the kitchen and we worked through until midnight
3. Later on Dad ate a cheese sandwich

I am trying to use a regular expression to search for any lines containing the words "Dad" and "kitchen". They don't have to be next to each other, but just somewhere on the line.

In the example above, only the 2nd line should be found.

I have tried:

```
[kitchen] dad
```

But that matches the 2nd and 3rd lines, presumably because the [kitchen] says find any lines containing any of those characters, rather than the entire word, and and words containing "dad".

I also tried:

```
[\bkitchen\b] dad
```

But that doesn't work either.

Apologies for posting this question, I am seemingly at risk of being blocked on Stackoverflow from asking any more questions because my questions have not been well received, but I'm not sure why, I try to ask clear questions...

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why use regex? Most programming languages have some sort of _contains/indexOf_ function on strings which are made just for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either *dad* is followed by *kitchen*:

```
dad.*kitchen
```

Or *kitchen* is followed by *dad*:

```
kitchen.*dad
```

Putting the two together:

```
(dad.*kitchen|kitchen.*dad)
```

Also, remember about case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex which uses lookarounds. And don't forget to enable `i` modifier to do a case insensitive match.

```
^(?=.*?\bkitchen\b)(?=.*?\bdad\b)(?!\bkitchen\sdad\b|\bdad\skitchen\b).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bW0nH8/4)

Comment: I don't see the reason for `(?!\bkitchen\sdad\b|\bdad\skitchen\b)` doesn't OP only want to check for presence of both words?

Comment: `They don't have to be next to each other`, updated my demo link.

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression will do what you asked for but BlackBear is right, most programming languages provide an easier way to determine if a line of text contains a substring.

```
^.*(?:dad.*kitchen|kitchen.*dad).*$
```

*Note: the expression will always match the whole line.*

Make sure to use the `i` flag while matching to ensure a case-insensitive match.
Alternativly you can use change the expression like this:

```
^(?i).*(?:dad.*kitchen|kitchen.*dad).*$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gZ6lJ0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Using `lookahead`, this regex should work.

```
(?:(?=\bdad\b).*(?=\bkitchen\b).*)|(?:(?=\bkitchen\b).*(?=\bdad\b).*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aC9kJ1/1)